# SMTP is not sending emails in gmail business account

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-workspace

This code is working well in gmail personal account, but when I try to use gmail business account, it is not working and keeps giving an error. 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

```
void SendEmail()
{
    DataTable data = GetData();
    DataTable email_data = GetEmailData();
    data.TableName = "Employee_Data";

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(data);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            String from = "seong@abcd.net";

            for (int i = 0; i < email_data.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                String to = email_data.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to))
                {
                    mm.Subject = "Employees Attachment";
                    mm.Body = "Employees Exported Attachment";

                    mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "Employees.xlsx"));
                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                    credentials.UserName = "seong@abcd.net";
                    credentials.Password = "1234";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding mm.Header  = "From: <postmaster@abcd.net>"

Comment: also, I am not sure your smtp.Host is smpt.gmail.com, it could be smtp.abcd.net

Comment: You should configure your google account to lower privilege.

Comment: I havent actually tried this but these links may help https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
The account should not use 2nd verification in gmail if you want to use SMTP.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en&ref_topic=7189195

I can't control those things, I ask the administrator allow not to use 2nd verification.
So I can work with that account using SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Smtp method for Business Gsuite

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Username   = "Enter the user ID"; // SMTP account username
// SMTP account password
$mail->Password   = "Enter your password";

$mail->SetFrom('Enter the User ID', 'Subject');
$mail->AddReplyTo("Enter the User ID", "Subject");

$mail->AddAddress($to, "Name");

$mail->Subject    = "Contact Enquiry";

$message = '';

$mail->MsgHTML($message);

if($mail->Send()){
   $mail->ClearAddresses();  
   echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
} else {
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Login to your Gmail Account: Go to --> Settings --> Forwarding and POP/IMAP --> Enable IMAP After that Go to Gmail Account Settings --> Security --> Less secure app access (Turn it ON). SMTP Method for business gmail will works perfectly.